# May pstool call lualatex instead of pdflatex?

Tags: pdftex, luatex, pstool

I'm working with a document containing huge bibliography.
That forced me to switch to lualatex, because pdflatex generated errors:

```
{\csname blx@nih@author\endcsname {{{hash=8ce87b4dc27b48d204336f9068c\ETC.
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=5000000].
<argument> ...688a7851}{family={Kotam{ä}ki}, fami
                                              lyi={K\bibinitperiod }, gi...
l.202365       }            
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

The lualatex handled the file correctly, but then I needed to add a figure, which required use of pstool to replace a few placeholders with LaTeX processed text.
Unfortunately, it seems that pstool calls pdflatex again, as I get the following in the figure-pstool.log:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2019/dev/Debian (prelo
aded format=latex 2018.12.25)  16 JAN 2019 22:54
entering extended mode
[...]
{\csname blx@nih@author\endcsname {{{hash=8ce87b4dc27b48d204336f9068c\ETC.
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=5000000].
<argument> ...iod }}}{{hash=dd6e000d600d547b04bd57
                                              d6485bc7bf}{family={Nogima...
l.202365       }

If you really absolutely need more capacity,
you can ask a wizard to enlarge me.
```

Is there any way to have pstool to call lualatex instead of pdflatex to avoid memory limitations?

Comment: pstool needs to call (dvi)latex to use psfrag but why is it having to process the bibliography?

Comment: anyway you always have the option of doing what pstool is automating, make a small document with just the image and the psfrag replacements process that with latex/dvips/ps2pdf to get a pdf file then just include that using graphics package in your main lualatex document

Comment: A few of those placeholders are supposed to be replaced by the bibliography references.

Comment: ah:-)..........

Comment: The trick with the small document does not allow me to add references. The figure that caused the problem was a kind of "map" of the document. It was supposed to provide hyperlinks to different sections of the document and bibliography references placed in the block diagram of the system described.

Comment: I suppose you could try dvilualatex

Comment: The funny thing is that even when I removed all references from psfrag replacements, the figure-pstool.bbl is still generated, and it is just a copy of the main doc bbl file.

Comment: Generation of the huge figure-pstool.bbl is a result of using \psfragfig* instead of \psfragfig. However, it was suggested in pstool documentation: "...Therefore, I recommend when setting such figures up in your document to use the \psfragfig* command..."

Comment: However, when I changed the \psfragfig* to \psfragfig, the problem with Tex capacity disappeared, but all references (even those internal) remained unresolved and got converted to "??".

Comment: Wow, I’m glad to hear someone is using the bibliography integration I added to the package :-) I have no idea if dvilualatex works here — if it does, it would be a good addition to the package!

Comment: Lualatex seems to handle the document without errors. However, when I try to run dvipdfm later on, I get the following error: xdvipdfmx:fatal: Unable to find TFM file "[lmsans10-regular]:+tlig;".

Comment: I have reduced the list of authors, as described in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/470584/42835 so that now I can compile my document with pdflatex. However, now it appears that pstool is not compatible with hyperref.